# Проблема с компиляцией проекта Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, компиляция

Вопрос новичка, сразу говорю.
В самом начале работы, при компиляции выдает ошибку :
`can't  until host application is defined`

На одном из форумов задавался этот же вопрос по `Delphi 2010`, и ответили: надо было создавать не новую форму, a `Application`
Но:

- В `Delphi7` есть просто `Application`, a в `2009` просто `Application` нет, а есть  `MDI`, `SDI` и `VCL Forms Application` (а также `Console`, `Control Panel` и `Service Application`). У меня задача самая примитивная, что выбрать?
- в `Delphi7` эта проблема решалась тем, что когда все написал, можно сохранить проект - а что, в `2009` так нельзя, надо сразу создавать?

Comment: Все можно, только Вы зашли немного со средины. Создали не проект, а только файл, который может быть использован в проекте.

Answer (score 4):

VCL Forms Application - это как раз то, что вам нужно.